# How to perform an inner join between a local table and an external table in Access 2007 SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

I am trying to delete some data from an external table based on an inner join in Access 2007 with SQL in VBA, but I am running into an issue with "invalid bracketing".

The code I am trying to use is as follows:

```
Dim FilePath, SQL as String
FilePath = "[\\Path\BEDB\" & DBModel & " BEDB.accdb]" 'DB model is a function that gets desired model name

SQL = "DELETE " & FilePath & ".[Part Number].*  FROM [Select Table] INNER JOIN " & FilePath & ".[Part Number] ON [Select Table].[Concatenate] = " & FilePath & ".[Part Number].[Concatenate] WHERE [Select Table].[Select] = True"
DBS.Execute SQL 'Delete the selected part numbers out of [Part Number] table
```

The invalid bracketing error comes from `[\\Path\BEDB\" & DBModel & " BEDB.accdb].[Part Number].[Concatenate]` in the inner join statement. Is there another way to represent the path to the external table without using [] or is it not possible to do joins on tables not linked to the database already?

Comment: Is the table stored in the external .accdb [linked](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) to your local database?  If not it cannot be joined to local data.

Comment: No, it is not linked. I was trying to do it without being linked, but if it's not possible without linking then I will make due with having them linked.